# Forcing local variables to be default-initialized

Tags: c++

In C++, plain-old-data (POD) local variables are uninitialized by default. I've noticed, though, that this leads to bugs, since attempting to read the value of an uninitialized variable is undefined behavior.

Is there a way to force the compiler to automatically initialize all local variables? Perhaps a compiler that has this feature built in, or a compiler switch for one of the common compilers, like GCC or Clang? I would be fine with a Gnu extension; it doesn't have to be standard.

I would expect the variables to be default-initialized, meaning that an `int` would be set to 0.

I am bored with assigning all local `int`s and private class fields to 0.

Comment: I didn't know typing `= 0` was that bad.

Comment: You don't pay for what you don't use. Therefore, locals are only initialised when explicitly requested. If you used a compiler switch, your code would instantly be non-portable.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing it so often you're bored. Why do all your objects need to be zero initialized? And when you do need to do it, does it not immediately make the code clearer? This sounds like a problem with your code.

Comment: @DanielFischer Although I find the Java/C# language-level (i.e. ignoring runtime guarnatees) approach better here: it is invalid source code if a local variable is used before it is *known* to be assigned. Now, granted various C++ compilers can be configured with such warnings ..

Comment: @Daniel & sftrabbit, actually this explicit initialization rule aimed to help on debug stage. If your variable should be zero you will initialize it explicitly anyway to help reader in understanding the code.

Comment: Isn't `PODType x{};` enough?

Comment: @Rapptz, may be some scribblers like it, I would like to focus on code than on technical staff like this.

Comment: @KerrekSB, it is for C++11, and why should I write this additional {}? It is not make code more clear or easy to read.

Comment: You could also argue that it's clearer to be explicit about "this data is zero" than to rely on a magic effect. It's ultimately a design choice of the language, and you have to live with it. I would find it much more confusing if you started relying on some compiler-dependent behaviour.

Comment: some tools (like Coverity) are able to detect those non-initialized POD class members and report them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a proposal to compile linux kernel with zero initialized local variables, see the presentation from linux.conf this year https://youtu.be/FY9SbqTO5GQ?t=742

To accomplish this the presenter team used an experimental gcc switch `finit-local-vars`, patch is here https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2014-06/msg00615.html

I hope this will be eventually merged to gcc main branch and adopted widely. Literally every code style guide I've seen demanded C/C++ coders to make an explicit zero assignment `= 0` wherever they defined a variable. This is error prone and meaningless monkey work.

**EDIT 2022**: A switch `-ftrivial-auto-var-init` was added to GCC 12

Answer (score 1):

There is no switch to do that I know about, and even if it *did* exist, it would be only a "debug" feature, not to be used in production code.

Example: Electric fence library has an option to initialize memory to 0 or `0xff`

> EF_FILL
>       When set to a value between 0 and 255, every byte of allocated memory is initialized to that value. This can help detect reads of uninitialized memory. When set to -1, some memory is filled with zeroes (the operating system default on most systems) and some memory will retain the values written to it during its last use.

(only works for *allocated* memory, not automatic memory).

Relying on a switch that isn't defined as/in a standard would make your code non-portable. At some point, someone will use your code to cross compile it on other platforms and that will fail.

As a help/safeguard, some tools like [Coverity](https://www.synopsys.com/software-integrity/security-testing/static-analysis-sast.html) (note: I'm not affiliated with this company) can detect uninitialized POD members in your code. There may be free tools that do the same.

So what I would do in cases of one or 2 POD members (c++11):

```
class Foo
{
   ...
   private:
      int x = 0;
      int y = 0;
};
```

If you have a zillion members, maybe create a POD class/struct, create 1 member with this type and initialize it to 0 using whatever initialization works best:

```
class Foo
{
   ...
   private:
      struct Pod
      {
        int x,y,z,whatever;
      };
      Pod m = {0};
};
```

That forces to access members like `m.x`, ... not transparent

OR (maybe slightly hacky but works), create a POD structure, then *inherit* your class from it. You can now apply `memset` on the size of the POD structure in the default constructor

```
  struct Pod
  {
    Pod()
    {
       std::memset(this,0,sizeof(Pod));
    }
    int x,y,z,whatever;
  };

  class Foo : private Pod
  {
     public:
       ...
      private:
        std::string name;
        std::vector<int> elements;
  };
```

The `sizeof(Pod)` value ensures that `memset` only sets the members of `Pod` to 0.

If `Pod` comes from a C structure that you cannot change, you can move the `memset` statement in `Foo` constructor, keeping `sizeof(Pod)`

Comment: The question is not how to find missing assignments and rewrite the code, most of static and dynamic analyzers can find uninitialized variable. The question is how to avoid this on compiler level for existing code and save time. It is another paradigm.