# Isn't there any gcc compiler option to force initialization of floating point variable

Tags: c

I ask this question because there is a super convenient compiler option in gfortran, especially when dealing with legacy software:

```
gfortran -finit-real=snan
```

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Code-Gen-Options.html

This way all floating points variables get initialized by default to a signalling NaN and cause a runtime error if used before set.

This kind of FORTRAN compiler options was already present in the 80s if I remember correctly (at least on SUN workstations), so this is not something new.

I fail to see an equivalent of gfortran option in gcc. Why?
Isn't it the same code generation backend?

The `-Wuninitialized` of gcc does not catch all, and `-Wmaybe-uninitialized` catches too much (false alarms...)... I'd like a RUNTIME check which is somehow complementary, especially when there are too many warnings in legacy code.

Comment: Did you tried the flag `-O` with `Wuninitialized`? Or, `-Wall` (gcc 2.96+)? Also, have you tried to using `valgrid` (valgrind.org)? Its can automatically detect many memory management and threading bugs, and profile your programs in detail.

Comment: Can't you update your code to initialized with nan? Then you get the behavior you want regardless of compiler flags.

Comment: C is not, generally speaking, a handholding kind of language.

Comment: my guess: portability issues

Comment: Yes I remember having the same thought when I moved from FORTRAN at University. It would be a useful thing to switch on in debug builds.

Comment: The answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661074/forcing-local-variables-to-be-default-initialized may be relevant, but the GCC patch discussed initialises to zero which is not what you want but most likely if it were ever implemented at all.

Comment: Same code generation back end perhaps, but contrary to the language definition and aims perhaps.

Comment: @Micromuncher "Can't you update your code to initialized with nan?" I'm not sure how that would catch use of _uninitialized_ floats!

Comment: @Clifford I see it more like a runtime-check to help finding bugs, than a conveniency to help hiding bugs. It's true that legacy FORTRAN compilers used to put local variables in heap rather than stack  without requiring the mandatory SAVE instruction, and did initialize them to zero, thus the -finit=zero makes more sense in FORTRAN context...

Comment: @acarlstein ah, yes, valgrind has not super detailed report about which variable, but it seems it can help that there are some though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52399300/can-i-get-valgrind-to-tell-me-which-value-is-uninitialized

Comment: There are static analysis tools for that - you can set a rule that requires initialisation of all local variables.  Setting aggressive optimisation levels will often yield better "uninitialised at point of use" results.

Comment: @IanAbbott Sorry, my point was use your favorite search tool and replace anything that looks uninitialized with a nan (that or use lint or codecheck).

Comment: @Clifford some fields inside large data structures are un-initialized and gcc doesn't analyze that, I have no powerful static analyzer available, it's not critical software... It seems that the bug comes from a routine filling the structure from file that fails to initialize some fields (or fails to correctly check integrity of data files, whatever...). A cheap and simple complementary runtime check would suffice to detect the problem, thus my request...